# How to create terminal commands for programs installed from source

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, monit

I recently tried to install monit on Ubuntu Natty from source. Here's my code:

```
apt-get -y install openssl libssl-dev bison flex
mkdir src && cd src
wget http://mmonit.com/monit/dist/monit-5.3.2.tar.gz
tar xzf monit-5.3.2.tar.gz
cd monit-5.3.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/monit
make && make install
```

However, when I install Monit using `apt-get` I am able to call monit directly from the command line using the keyword `monit`. I am not able to do so when I do the install from source. The same goes for PHP.

How can I enable this feature for when I install Monit (and other Linux programs) from source?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

```
printf "\nPATH=/usr/local/monit/bin:\${PATH}\n" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

This will apply for the currently logged in user (in my case root). To make it system-wide simply replace `~/.profile` with `/etc/profile`.

So now I can can call `monit` (and any other program I install from source).

Comment: what do you get when you type echo $PATH ?

Comment: I get `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`. I'm somewhat of noob in customizing linux, so I just wanted to know if there was a file somewhere I could edit with nano, and how to edit it.

Comment: yes there is, check the answers, you could also add a link to the binary under any of those directories, when you type <command> those variables are searched in order until command is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/profile` to add the path `/usr/local/monit` to the `PATH` variable.

For ex, if you earlier had this.

`PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

You could change it to

`PATH="/usr/local/monit:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Comment: +1. Also: @Chuck, mind that if a program is found in one of the *earlier* directories in $PATH, the later directories are not searched. So if you want your 'locally installed' binaries to have preference, add them at the **beginning** of PATH.

Comment: Thanks. However, looking at my /etc/profile file, it does not have the path variable. I've posted the contents of the file here: http://pastebin.com/70stiZQx

Comment: I tried `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/monit/bin` then `source ~/.bashrc`, but it didn't persist when I logged out and logged in again

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution to this using .profile. Will add this as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using that command to install it will put it in /usr/local/monit, which won't be in your $PATH, as others have said.  There are several options besides modifying your path, though.  For instance, you can create a symbolic link from the real executable to one in your path. So if the executable is /usr/local/monit/monit, you can

```
ln -s /usr/local/monit/monit /usr/local/bin/monit
```

The advantage of creating the symbolic link is it will work for all users.

You can also create an alias, but that would only work for apps that run as you.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean I would have to install Monit twice i.e. using `apt-get install monit`, then doing my own install from source, all before creating the symlink?!

Comment: No.  There's only one real copy of the executable.  the "ln -s" command will create a symbolic link (pointer) to the one real copy.  It's like a shortcut in Windows, if you are more familiar with Windows.